# liblbfgs compile in c++

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, c++

Has anyone tried out compiling programs with LBFGS package available through *liblbfgs*. I believe its a popular [package](http://www.chokkan.org/software/liblbfgs/). I can't seem to compile the sample program with the following command:

`g++ sample.cpp -o sample`

Comment: What errors are you getting, and what type of system are you running on? I use this library frequently and have never had a compilation problem.

Comment: Its giving me undefined reference to `lbfgs_free`, `lbfgs_malloc`, `lbfgs`. I made sure that the headers were in the current directory. I know, I must be missing something trivial.

Comment: At the very least, you should link with the library: try `g++ sample.cpp -o sample -llbfgs`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I didn't know the exact name what to plugin in linking. Previously, tried -llbfgs-1.10 and -lbfgs but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Vincent in the comment solves the problem about linking error

```
 g++ sample.cpp -o sample -llbfgs
```

FYI. This helped in building the crfsuite package